# MOSFET Switch for Tuned LC Tank

Tags: oscillator, tuning

I am trying to implement the circuit as shown below.

I essentially want to be able to control the gate voltage of the NMOS to change the resonant frequency from 5GHz to 2.5GHz. For a transistor size of 20um/1um, I swept the gate voltage for about 20 points from 0 to 1V and the resonant frequency did not change (maybe by a few kHz).

The issue seems to be that the source voltage is not fixed. I checked the DC voltage at the source node and it varies depending on the gate voltage. There is also no path to ground. Do I need to add a large resistor to provide a path to ground for the DC current?

Could anyone provide how this issue is solved or refer to useful documents? All documents I see just model the MOSFET as a switch and don't actually show how it is implemented.

The voltage swing at the output is around 100mVpp. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if you hang a lossy series RC in parallel with the 1ank, what happens? what parasitics does the 300fF include in its SPICE model?

Comment: Your transistor W/L sounds pretty small to be connected to 300fF. With a gate voltage of only 1V you may not have enough Vgs for the transistor to conduct.  What is the threshold voltage? Why are you using an NMOS instead of a PMOS? Why not connect the NMOS/capacitor to ground instead of VDD? Where is the body connected?

Comment: I tried connecting the nmos and capacitor to ground. The threshold is around 400mV. The body is connected to ground as shown in my diagram.